# Deleted variable in a barplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, graph, cptbarplot

I need your help with a barplot in R.

I have a data frame called "answers", it is something like this:

v0= Chicago, Miami,Orlando, New York, (50 cities more)
v1= employee,  Unemployed, looking for a job
.

I need help with a barplot, I'm doing this:

1. for my first column
   `a1=answers[,c("v0")]`
   `b1=table(a1)`
2. For my second column
   `a2=answers[,c("v1")]` }
   `b2=table(a2)`

Then I match both tables in just one:

`d=table(a2,b2)`
`d1=prop.table(d, margin=2)`
`d2=percent(d1,digits = 3)`
the result show me the number of person employees, unemployees and looking for a job in each city.

Finally i make a barplot:
`graph=barplot((d2),las=1,beside=T, horiz=F,ces.names=1.5,col=..........)`

My question is:

How can I delete one or more options from V2, that means just make a barplot about the results for "employee" and "nonemployee" and remove "looking for a job"

Comment: Using subset of your dataframe allows you to keep it unchanged if your don't want to create another dataframe. For example `barplot(subset(d2, selection_variable%in%c("employee", "nonemployee"))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just remove the rows of your data frame which consist of the variable value = "looking for job", You can easily use this piece of code:

```
data <- data.frame(
  v0 = c("employee", "Unemployed", "looking for a job"),
  v1 = c("Chicago", "Miami","Orlando"))

data <- data[!data$v0 %in% c("looking for a job"), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by subsetting the data.frame. For example:

```
graph = ((barplot(d2[d2$selection_variable <= some_value, ]), ...)
```